React native "Can't merge pod_target_xcconfig for pod targets"
when I try to run pod install, I get this in my logs "[!] Can't merge pod_target_xcconfig for pod targets: ["expo-dev-menu", "Main", "SafeAreaView", "Vendored"]. Singular build setting DEFINES_MODULE has different values.
[!] Can't merge pod_target_xcconfig for pod targets: ["expo-dev-menu", "Main", "SafeAreaView", "Vendored"]. Singular build setting DEFINES_MODULE has different values.
"
this occurs after trying to resolve this "[!] The following Swift pods cannot yet be integrated as static libraries:
The Swift pod FirebaseCoreInternal depends upon GoogleUtilities, which does not define modules. To opt into those targets generating module maps (which is necessary to import them from Swift when building as static libraries), you may set use_modular_headers! globally in your Podfile, or specify :modular_headers => true for particular dependencies.
The Swift pod FirebaseFirestore depends upon FirebaseCore, FirebaseCoreExtension, and FirebaseFirestoreInternal, which do not define modules. To opt into those targets generating module maps (which is necessary to import them from Swift when building as static libraries), you may set use_modular_headers! globally in your Podfile, or specify :modular_headers => true for particular dependencies.
The Swift pod FirebaseStorage depends upon FirebaseAppCheckInterop, FirebaseAuthInterop, FirebaseCore, FirebaseCoreExtension, and GTMSessionFetcher, which do not define modules. To opt into those targets generating module maps (which is necessary to import them from Swift when building as static libraries), you may set use_modular_headers! globally in your Podfile, or specify :modular_headers => true for particular dependencies."
I had tried to resolve the original error by following this from the firebase documentation:
"Beginning with firebase-ios-sdk v9+ (react-native-firebase v15+) you must tell CocoaPods to use frameworks.
Open the file ./ios/Podfile and add this line inside your targets (right before the use_react_native line in current react-native releases that calls the react native Podfile function to get the native modules config):
use_frameworks! :linkage => :static
To use Static Frameworks on iOS, you also need to manually enable this for the project with the following global to your /ios/Podfile file:
right after use_frameworks! :linkage => :static
$RNFirebaseAsStaticFramework = true
Notes: React-Native-Firebase uses use_frameworks, which has compatibility issues with Flipper & Fabric.
Flipper: use_frameworks is not compatible with Flipper. You must disable Flipper by commenting out the :flipper_configuration line in your Podfile. Flipper is deprecated in the react-native community and this will not be fixed - Flipper and react-native-firebase will never work together on iOS.
New Architecture: Fabric is partially compatible with use_frameworks!. If you enable the bridged / compatibility mode, react-native-firebase will compile correctly and be usable."
I've tried many things and I'm getting one or the other in my logs. How can I resolve this? Thanks!
tried "  $RNFirebaseAsStaticFramework = true", "  config = use_native_modules!", "  use_frameworks! :linkage => :static", manually setting them and using post install to set them, and more
